# Xamarin forms dynamically set size of Grid

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm porting a app from UWP to Xamarin Forms (Android and iOS). In UWP I have a grid that needs to be strictly square - regardless of the size of the window. At present code behind captures `SizeChanged` event, and then picks the smallest dimension and sets both `Width` and `Height` properties to that size. Now, the trouble is `Height` and `Width` properties appear to be read-only from C#. I have tried setting `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` properties - but these do not appear to have any effect, unless I'm missing another step, something like re-draw function call?

Also, potentially there is a better way to achieve this functionality that I not aware of? It has to be window size agnostic and work in both portrait and landscape orientations.

Update - relevant bits of code below:
Xaml of the View:

```xml
<Grid SizeChanged="Grid_SizeChanged"  Background="Black" >
        <Grid Margin="10" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" x:Name="PlotMap" SizeChanged="PlotMap_SizeChanged">
            <!-- Omitted for brevity  -->
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

And C# codebehind:

```cs
        private void Grid_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            PlotMap.WidthRequest = Math.Min(PlotMap.Width, PlotMap.Height);
            PlotMap.HeightRequest = Math.Min(PlotMap.Width, PlotMap.Height);
            this.ForceLayout();
            // above code appers to have no effect on grid sizing
        }

        private void PlotMap_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // unrelated code that triggers the the update of the plot
        }
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: @Jason I've updated my post to include relevant bits of code

Comment: Do you want to set height or width at run time?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Yes, I need an element to always be square, regardless of screen resolution and orientation

Comment: You can set  a specific value for the width  and of your element .

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT as far as I can tell Height and Width properties are read-only.